# How to Display BackContent For Secondary Tile in Windwos Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In WP8.0 tile is display front and back, When coming to WP8.1 tile display only front, How to give backcontent for Secondary tile.

In WP 8.0

```
 StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
 {
  BackgroundImage =new Uri(@"Shared/ShellContent/Snow.png",UriKind.Relative),
  Title = ((CheckBox)sender).Content.ToString(),
  Count = 1,
  BackBackgroundImage =new Uri(@"Shared/ShellContent/Snow.png", UriKind.Relative),
  BackTitle = "Back Title",
  BackContent = "Back Content"
```

};

in WP 8.1

```
var secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(
                "secondaryTileId",
                "Text shown on tile",
                "secondTileArguments",
                new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/rainier.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
                TileSize.Square150x150);

        bool isPinned = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flip tile has been changed in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime apps. In WP8 app, it is of two parts, one front and one back. but in WP8.1 RT app, this is not the same as the old flip tile since the front is only an image with no text and back is just text with no image, see The tile template catalog (Windows Runtime apps)

In WP8.1, how to create Flip or Cyclic tile? The answer is to call TileUpdater.EnableNotificationQueue with true and add tiles in a series. With this approach you can combine any of tiles and make your own flip or cyclic tile.

Please refer to this article for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/10/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-live-tiles.aspx